# jQuery UI Selectable disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using jQuery UI Selectable for list items in Ordered list, But i just want to disable only one list item from that ol, is their any way to do that?
here is my code

```
<ol id="selectable"> 
   <li>enable & selectable</li>
   <li>enable & selectable</li>
   <li>enable & selectable</li>
   <li>disable & not selctable</li>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selectable widget provides a [`filter`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-filter) option that can be used to include children of the matched element:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: ".something" //Give the elements to be selectable a class
});
```

Your HTML would then look something like this:

```
<ol id="selectable"> 
   <li class="something">enable & selectable</li>
   <li class="something">enable & selectable</li>
   <li class="something">enable & selectable</li>
   <li>disable & not selctable</li>
</ol>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7J8N/2/).

If the `li` you want to exclude is always the last one, like in your example, you could avoid adding a class to each of the `li` elements and use the `:not` and `:last` selectors:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: "li:not(:last)"
});
```